# Does insert performance get impacted in MongoDb if no value is passed for the indexed column

Tags: mongodb, indexing

MongoDB has a dynamic schema. Some of the columns might not exist in all the document. For instance, an 'employee collection' can have id, name, salary. But another document in this collection can have additional column previous_experience. By default, all the columns are indexed.

Now, if I insert a document with id, name, and salary, it will update the index on id, name, and salary. Will this insertion also update the index on prenvious_company? In other words, every new index will slow down all insertion, not matter if values are passed to this new column or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `id, name  and salary` keys have single field indexes. MongoDB will create 3 indexes on this collection based on the sorted order of field.

Since you haven't created an index on key `previous_company`, the insertion will not affect index on `previous_company`.

You may consider using [sparse indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-sparse/). Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field.

Comment: I am talking about the case where all of four fields have an index, but the newly added document has only three fields. Would 4th field index will be updated?

Comment: Yes, non-sparse indexes contain all documents in a collection, storing null values for those documents that do not contain the indexed field

Comment: Thanks Astro, that answer my question.